# Monotone series increases and decreases depending on first term. What is the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried to write down the proof for this series. Getting the value is easy assuming convergence. But I couldn't formally prove that it converges using monotone threorem. The series is increasing for some values of $z$ and decreases for some values of $z$, but it is always monotone. How to find proceed now since we don't know if it increases or decreases? Please provide a formal solution.

> Q.Let $a>0$ and let $z_1>0$. Define $z_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+z_n} $for n$\in
> > N$. Show that the limit $(z_n)$ converges and find the limit (where a is just $a$ positive constant).

Comment: Did you mean $a$ as the parameter in the question, not $z$?

Comment: Please demonstrate some effort.  What have you tried?  If you assume convergence, can you obtain the value it converges to?  Now if $z_1$ is bigger or smaller than that value, it will determine the direction we go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Don't use monotonicity, go back to the definition.

- Find the limit $L$, assuming it exists.
- Check that $L>1$.
- Use basic algebra to show that $|z_{n+1}-L|<\frac1L\,|z_n-L|$.
- Explain how this solves the problem.